# RKeras "unknown url type: https" error six.urlretrieve (Python Code From R)

Tags: python, r, https, six, reticulate

TL;DR :-) fetching https urls is working in both python and R, but not when python code is run from R.

---

While running some code in documentation of package RKeras , I have repeatedly run into the fatal error : `"unknown url type: https"` The problem originates in Keras which is implemented in Python.

I dug into the problem and found that this was happening when Keras was calling the function `urlretrieve` in the module `six` to retrieve data from https url.

I then tested the code in iPython and found it to be working perfectly.

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve(url="https://www.google.com")
```

Then I try doing the same in R and it fails

```
<!-- language: lang-r -->
library(reticulate)
py_run_string('from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve')
py_run_string("urlretrieve(url='https://www.google.com')")
```

However, same thing works in R with plain http

```
<!-- language:lang-r -->
py_run_string("urlretrieve(url='http://www.google.com')")
```

For the record, https works fine within my R with packages like httr.

I am totally out of my depth here. What could be happening?

Here is some output about my env

R:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
# other attached packages:
# [1] reticulate_1.6 kerasR_0.8.0
```

And Python (as seen from R)

```
py_config()

version:        3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| 
(default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

Will much appreciate your time and effort.

---

Edit: Some more debug info in R:

```
py_run_string("from OpenSSL import SSL")
# ImportError: /xxx/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, I am posting a partial solution to my particular problem. This is not going to solve the general problem with Reticulate and SSL, but is a decent temporary **workaround** to help anyone using **KerasR or Keras and finding it is not able to download models and databases**

Keras / KerasR uses a cache to avoid future downloads of the same object. In my case, it is `~/.keras/`

So copy the URL of failed download from the console, download the object with the browser and save to keras' cache directory.

```
cache for models : ~/.keras/models/
cache for datasets : ~/.keras/datasets/
(where ~ is my home directory)
```

Of course, this is a workaround and I am still looking forward to someone posting a proper solution that works system-wide.

Comment: Hi R.S., thanks for this workaround - I was having a similar issue and it's good to know that it's possible to manually download Keras models. By any chance have you found a permanent solution to your problem?

Comment: @RoyalSwish No. Haven't looked all that farther into it actually, as I got busy with other things. I'll post here if I find something, or will welcome someone else's suggestions.